# Linq (GroupBy and Sum) over List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a structure:

```
List<List<string>> content
```

This is bascially the content from a comma seperated file. The first element in the list will be a list of strings representing the headers. All other element in the list will be a list of strings representing the values.

I am trying to run a query like below. Where "code" and "book" are two headers and I need to group by them 2 and sum by another header. This is my attemp but of course I cannot use the Groupby on the content directly as it is a list of lists.

```
List<List<string>> content = MyContent();

var linqResults = content
                  .GroupBy(x => new { Code = x["code"], Book = x["book"] })
                  .Select(g =>
                   {
                       return new
                       {
                           Book = g.Key.Book,
                           Code = g.Key.Code,
                           Total = g.SelectMany(x => x["columnToSum"].Sum())
                       };
                   });
```

Comment: I suggest you to parse csv file into list of strongly-typed entities (e.g. orders) instead of list of list of strings. Then calculating totals will look like `orders.GroupBy(o => new { o.Book, o.Code }).Select(g => new { g.Key.Book, g.Key.Code, Total = g.Sum(o => o.ColumnToSum) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Sergey's comment but You could do something like this:

```
var content = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>{ "book", "code", "columnToSum" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "10" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "5" },
            new List<string>{ "cde", "1", "6" },
        };

var headers = content.First();
var result = content.Skip(1)
    .GroupBy(s => new { Code = s[headers.IndexOf("code")], Book = s[headers.IndexOf("book")]})
    .Select(g => new
             {
                 Book = g.Key.Book,
                 Code = g.Key.Code,
                 Total = g.Select(s => int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])).Sum()
             });
```

Which returns:

```
{ Book = abc, Code = 1, Total = 15 }
{ Book = cde, Code = 1, Total = 6 }
```