# Linq: Sum() non-integer values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is a continuation from my previos question:
[Linq (GroupBy and Sum) over List<List<string>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779885/linq-groupby-and-sum-over-listliststring?noredirect=1#comment32950629_21779885)

I have a query like so:

```
var content = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>{ "book", "code", "columnToSum" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "10" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "5" },
            new List<string>{ "cde", "1", "6" },
        };

var headers = content.First();
var result = content.Skip(1)
    .GroupBy(s => new { Code = s[headers.IndexOf("code")], Book = s[headers.IndexOf("book")]})
    .Select(g => new
             {
                 Book = g.Key.Book,
                 Code = g.Key.Code,
                 Total = g.Select(s => int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])).Sum()
             });
```

This works fine but I'm just wondering how I can handle the case there the columnToSum is empty? So for example this gives me the error "Input string was not in a correct format" as the int.Parse fails

```
var content = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>{ "book", "code", "columnToSum" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "10" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "" },
            new List<string>{ "cde", "1", "6" },
        };
```

How can I handle this scenario gracefully?

Comment: You should turn your `List<string>`s into proper data structures if at all possible, e.g. a `Book` class with `string Name`, `int Code`, and `int? ColumnToSum` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, use `string.All(Char.IsDigit)` as pre-check:

```
Total = g.Select(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")]) && 
                      s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")].All(Char.IsDigit) ?
                      int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")]) : 0).Sum())
```

another would be to use `int.TryParse`:

```
int val = 0;
// ...
Total = g.Select(s => int.TryParse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")], out val) ?            
                      int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")]) : 0).Sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a zero onto the front of the string?

```
s => int.Parse("0" + s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])
```

Of course, it's a big hack. But it will solve your problem quickly and (quite) readably if the only exceptional case you're really worried about is the empty string.

I wonder where you're getting these empty strings from. If it's something you have control over like a SQL query, why don't you just change your query to give "0" for no value? (As long as the empty column isn't used in a different sense somewhere else in your code.)

Comment: "*Why don't you just add a zero onto the front of the string*" because that doesn't really answer the question - *"Sum() non-integer values"*. The `""` may be just for the purpose of the question and even if it isn't there is a good chance that whatever `""` represents could change in the future e.g. `"N/A"`. I agree with the second part of your question though, the *real* fix is to ensure that you don't end up with a non-numeric value in, what appears to be, a numeric column.

Comment: @James It does really answer the question **if the only exceptional case you're really worried about is the empty string**. This is also how the problem is described in the question, as opposed to the title.

Comment: yeah and what if it isn't the only exceptional case? The OP didn't say specifically that the only non-numeric value is an empty string you are *assuming* that's the case because of the example given. However, as far as we know it's exactly that - an example. Your answer solves the problem but it doesn't necessarily answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

That code assumes that empty string is 0:

```
Total = g.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Select(s => int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't going to look very nice...

```
g.Select(s => !s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")].Any(Char.IsDigit) ? 
    0 : Int32.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])).Sum()
```

However, you could wrap this up in a nice extension method

```
public static class StrExt
{
    public static int IntOrDefault(this string str, int defaultValue = 0)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || !str.Any(Char.IsDigit) ? defaultValue : Int32.Parse(str);
    }
}
...
g.Select(s => s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")].IntOrDefault()).Sum();
```

The extension method give you the flexibility to set whatever default value you want if the `str` is not a number - it defaults to `0` if the parameter is ommitted.

Answer (score 0):

Using lists here is problematic, and I would parse this into a proper data structure (like a Book class), which I think will clean up the code a bit. If you're parsing CSV files, take a look at [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), it's great library for these types of tasks, and it can parse into a data structure for you.

That being said, if you'd still like to continue using this paradigm, I think you can get the code fairly clean by creating two custom methods: one for dealing with the headers (one of the few places I'd use dynamic types to get rid of ugly strings in your code) and one for parsing the ints. You then get something like this:

```
var headers = GetHeaders(content.First());
var result = from entry in content.Skip(1)
                group entry by new {Code = entry[headers.code], Book = entry[headers.book] } into grp
                select new {
                    Book = grp.Key.Book,
                    Code = grp.Key.Code,
                    Total = grp.Sum(x => ParseInt(x[headers.columnToSum]))
                };

public dynamic GetHeaders(List<string> headersList){
    IDictionary<string, object> headers = new ExpandoObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < headersList.Count; i++)
        headers[headersList[i]] = i;        

    return headers;
}

public int ParseInt(string s){
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) 
        return i; 

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple lines in a lambda expression and return a value at end.
So, instead of

```
Total = g.Select(s => int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")])).Sum()
```

I would write

```
Total = g.Select(s => {
    int tempInt = 0;
    int.TryParse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")], out tempInt);
    return tempInt;                        
}).Sum()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
t = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>{ "book", "code", "columnToSum" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "10" },
            new List<string>{ "abc", "1", "5" },
            new List<string>{ "cde", "1", "6" },
        };

var headers = content.First();
var result = content.Skip(1)
    .GroupBy(s => new { Code = s[headers.IndexOf("code")], Book = s[headers.IndexOf("book")]})
    .Select(g => new
             {
                 Book = g.Key.Book,
                 Code = g.Key.Code,
                 Total = g.Select(s => int.Parse(s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")]!=""?s[headers.IndexOf("columnToSum")]:0)).Sum()
             });
```

Comment: So what if `columnToSum` is `ABC`? This has to work for *non-integer values* not just an empty string.